# Best approch for parsing large structured file with Apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have huge text file (in GBs) with plan text data in each line, which needs to be parsed and extracted to a structure for further processing. Each line has text with 200 charactor length and I have an Regular Expression to parse each line and split into different groups, which will later saved to a flat column data

data sample

```
1759387ACD06JAN1910MAR191234567ACRT
```

RegExp

```
(.{7})(.{3})(.{7})(.{7})(.{7})(.{4})
```

Data Structure

```
Customer ID, Code, From Date, To Date, TrasactionId, Product code
1759387,     ACD,  06JAN19,   10MAR19,  1234567,     ACRT
```

Please suggest a BEST approch to parse this huge data and push to In Memory grid, which will be used again by Spark Jobs for further processing, when respective APIs are invoked.

Comment: Could you please show your efforts and paste an example of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DF approach. Copy the serial file to HDFS using -copyFromLocal command
and use the below code to parse each records

I'm assuming the sample records in gireesh.txt as below

```
1759387ACD06JAN1910MAR191234567ACRT
2759387ACD08JAN1910MAY191234567ACRY
3759387ACD03JAN1910FEB191234567ACRZ
```

The spark code

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object Gireesh {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Operations..").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val pat="""(.{7})(.{3})(.{7})(.{7})(.{7})(.{4})""".r
    val headers = List("custid","code","fdate","tdate","tranid","prdcode")
    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("in/gireesh.txt")
      .map( x => {
              val y = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
              pat.findAllIn(x).matchData.foreach( m=> y.appendAll(m.subgroups))
           (y(0).toLong,y(1),y(2),y(3),y(4).toLong,y(5))
          }
      )
    val df = rdd.toDF(headers:_*)
    df.printSchema()
    df.show(false)

  }
}
```

gives the below results.

```
root
 |-- custid: long (nullable = false)
 |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tranid: long (nullable = false)
 |-- prdcode: string (nullable = true)

+-------+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|custid |code|fdate  |tdate  |tranid |prdcode|
+-------+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|1759387|ACD |06JAN19|10MAR19|1234567|ACRT   |
|2759387|ACD |08JAN19|10MAY19|1234567|ACRY   |
|3759387|ACD |03JAN19|10FEB19|1234567|ACRZ   |
+-------+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**EDIT1:**

You can have the map "transformation" in a separate function like below.

```
def parse(record:String) = {
  val y = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
  pat.findAllIn(record).matchData.foreach( m=> y.appendAll(m.subgroups))
  (y(0).toLong,y(1),y(2),y(3),y(4).toLong,y(5))
}
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("in/gireesh.txt")
  .map( x =>  parse(x) )
val df = rdd.toDF(headers:_*)
df.printSchema()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, I had issue with Dataset with 26 column limitation,  I created a class and its working great.  Thanks for the suggetions.

Comment: Glad that it worked.. and good to hear that you have overcome the limitation of 26 columns with the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell spark which file to read and how to process the content while reading it.

Here is an example:

```
val numberOfPartitions = 5 // this needs to be optimized based on the size of the file and the available resources (e.g. memory)
val someObjectsRDD: RDD[SomeObject] =
        sparkContext.textFile("/path/to/your/file", numberOfPartitions)
            .mapPartitions( 
                { stringsFromFileIterator =>
                  stringsFromFileIterator.map(stringFromFile => //here process the raw string and return the result)
                }
                , preservesPartitioning = true
              )
```

In the code snippet *SomeObject* is an object with the data structure from the question